# How can I override the node edit in Drupal 6?

Tags: 6, theming

I'm trying to override the "node edit"(using a "page-node-CONTENT-TYPE-edit.tpl.php") in drupal 6, and I'm stuck with the fact that I can't choose which field I want to publish in a specific edit page. I have to publish the whole $content or nothing !
I tried with drupal_render, $form etc... but nothing.

Does anyone have some clues on how I would be able to display the fields I want so I could design my edit page by content type?

I finally got it! It is quite simple; in fact, I just had to make a hook form filter, some "if" on `user_access()`, and rock and roll!

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you are asking here, but if you are trying to change the layout of the node edit form, you might check out the http://drupal.org/project/nodeformcols module that allows you to change the node edit/create form with a pretty straightforward drag and drop interface within CCK.